# Prove that the trajectory of $P$ is a circle in $3D$ and find its properties

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, dynamical-systems, cross-product, circular-motion

A point $P=(x,y,z)$ starts off at $P(0)= (x_0, y_0, z_0)$.  Its time derivative is given by

$ \dfrac{d P}{dt} = a \times P $

where $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ a unit vector, and $\times$ is the cross product.

Show that the trajectory $P(t)$ is a circle; find the unit normal vector to its plane, and its radius.

**My attempt:**  It is intuitively clear that the trajectory will be a circle, because $a \times P$ points perpendicular to the axis $a$ and to the point $P(t)$, the radius of this circle would be $ \| (I -  {aa}^T ) P(0) \|$.

I am looking for a formal proof of this statement.

Your help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** As the comment by @JohnAlexiou below suggests, this can be proven if we prove that: (1) $P$ lies on a sphere.  (2) $P$ lies on a plane.

(1) Can be proven as follows:

$\dfrac{d}{dt} ( P \cdot P ) = 2 P \cdot \dfrac{dP}{dt} = 0 $

because $ a \times P $ is perpendicular to $P$.  These proves that

$ P \cdot P = \text{Constant} = P(0) \cdot P(0) $

(2) Can be proven as follows:

$ \dfrac{d}{dt} ( a \cdot P ) = a \cdot \left( \dfrac{dP}{dt} \right) = a \cdot ( a \times P) = 0 $

Therefore,

$ a \cdot P = \text{Constant} = a \cdot P(0) $

And this is an equation of a plane.

Hence, $P(t)$ lies on the intersection of the sphere $P(t) \cdot P(t) = P(0) \cdot P(0) $ (this sphere is centered at the origin) and the plane $ a \cdot P(t) = a \cdot P(0) $

The distance between the center of the sphere (which is the origin) and the plane is

$ d = | a \cdot P(0) |$

Therefore the radius of the circle is $ r = \sqrt{ P(0) \cdot P(0) - P(0) ^T {a a }^T P(0) } = \sqrt{ P(0)^T ( I - {aa}^T) P(0) } = \| (I-{aa}^T ) P(0) \|$

Comment: You need to prove two things: a) Trajectory belongs to a sphere of some center and radius such that $(P-c)\cdot(P-c) = R^2$ and the trajectory remains planar such that $a \cdot P = a \cdot P_0$.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll work on this idea.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou  Thanks again, your idea worked very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have I think a solution to your question, but it might not be the most straightforward approach.

Start with the given equation

$$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{p} = \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{p} \tag{1}$$

Now decompose the location of the particle into a part parallel to $\boldsymbol{a}$ and a part perpendicular

$$ \boldsymbol{p}=\boldsymbol{a}\lambda+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right)\mu \tag{2}$$

where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are scalars (that can be variable at this point) and $\boldsymbol{u}$ is an arbitrary vector that is perpendicular (and thus $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 0$ at all times). This vector also might change with time at this point, but it will maintain its perpendicularity. Also note that without loss of generality, you can state that $\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 1$ since the magnitude of $\boldsymbol{u}$ can be absorbed into $\mu$.

Based on the above conditions, the derivative of the position is

$$ \dot{\boldsymbol{p}}=\boldsymbol{a}\dot{\lambda}+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}\right)\mu+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right)\dot{\mu} \tag{3}$$

where $\dot{\lambda}$, $\dot{\mu}$ and $\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}$ any changes to these quantities possible. Equate (1) to (3) to get

$$\boldsymbol{a}\dot{\lambda}+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right)\dot{\mu}+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}\right)\mu=\boldsymbol{a}\times\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right)\mu \tag{4}$$

for which you can surmise that $\dot{\lambda}=0$ and $\dot{\mu}=0$ by matching terms left to right and (4) now takes the form

$$\mu(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{u}})=\mu(\boldsymbol{a}\times\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right))$$

or more simply

$$\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{u}} =-\boldsymbol{u}\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right) \tag{5}$$

Note that (2) now is a planar equation because $$\require{cancel} \left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}\right)=\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)\lambda+\cancel{\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}\right)}\mu = \text{(const.)}$$

So we have shown that the trajectory remains on the plane perpendicular to $\boldsymbol{a}$.

Now is the time to understand the behavior of $\boldsymbol{u}$.

But before we proceed, note the initial position of the particle leads to $$\boldsymbol{p}_{0}=\boldsymbol{a}\lambda+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{u}_{0}\right)\mu \tag{6}$$

that has the solution of

$$\begin{aligned}
   \lambda & =\frac{\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}_{0}\right)}{\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)} \\
   \mu & = \frac{\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{u}_{0}\times\boldsymbol{p}_{0}\right)}{\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)} \end{aligned} \tag{7}$$

and it depends on the choice of arbitrary vector $\boldsymbol{u}_0 = \boldsymbol{u}(t=0)$.

Now back to $\boldsymbol{u}$. Suppose there are two basis vectors, $\boldsymbol{e}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_2$, that define $\boldsymbol{u}$ to be of unit length as such:

$$\boldsymbol{u}=\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cos\theta+\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\sin\theta \tag{8}$$

where $\theta$ is an arbitrary value, and $\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{2} = 0$. At this point, the basis vectors might change with time but we suspect they don't. We can investigate this by examining equation (5) and recognizing that

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}=\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}\cos\theta+\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}\sin\theta-\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\dot{\theta}\sin\theta+\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\dot{\theta}\cos\theta \tag{9}$$

So equation (5) is now

$$\small \boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}\cos\theta+\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}\sin\theta-\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\dot{\theta}\sin\theta+\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\dot{\theta}\cos\theta=-\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cos\theta+\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\sin\theta\right)$$

which yields two equations considering the arbitrary nature of $\theta$

$$ \begin{aligned}
(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1})+(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{2})\dot{\theta}+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)\boldsymbol{e}_{1}&=0\\(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2})-(\boldsymbol{a}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{1})\dot{\theta}+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{a}\right)\boldsymbol{e}_{2}&=0\end{aligned}$$

Now we project the above two equations along the basis vectors, to get

$$\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}\right)=\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\right)=0\\\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}\right)=\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\right)=0$$

with the simple solution of

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}=\omega_{2}\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\\\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}=\omega_{1}\boldsymbol{e}_{1}$$

but, it can be shown the solution of the above general solution is actually trivial.

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}=0\\\dot{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}=0$$

There is a long part here where I solve the above as an ODE using eigenvalue diagonalization but it really goes nowhere else other than $\omega_1=0$ and $\omega_2=0$ is a solution.

The result is that the basis vectors *can* be constant and provide a solution to (1) in the form of

$$\boxed{\boldsymbol{p}=\boldsymbol{a}\lambda+\left(\boldsymbol{a}\times\left(\boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cos\theta+\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\sin\theta\right)\right)\mu} \tag{10}$$

the above is a circle on the plane, and if we decide that $\theta=0$ when $t-0$ then

$$ \boldsymbol{e}_1 = \boldsymbol{u}_0 $$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_2$ can be derived as perpendicular to both $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_1$.

I do not feel very satisfied with the above, but it gets to where you need to go (maybe). Maybe it is circular argument